# how to do nested routing

Tags: nestjs

Can someone recommend how to properly (nestjs way) implement nested router? For example,

> `/users/12/characters/765/tools`

I'd like to have users controller and characters controller that is dependent on users (sub router) in separate files
( if this is not recommended way, could you suggest alternatives? ) thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot put some controller inside another. What you _can_ do on the other hand is to add a `UserController` that contains specific routes for specific actions. I can't post any concrete answer for now but if you tell me what you would like to do maybe I can help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this in separate controllers:

```
@Controller('users') 
export class UsersController
{...}

@Controller('users/:userId/characters')
export class CharactersController
{...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [router module](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/router-module)

```
RouterModule.register([
  {
    path: 'admin',
    module: AdminModule,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        module: DashboardModule,
      },
      {
        path: 'metrics',
        module: MetricsModule,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```